# Как сделать проверку на количество символов в сообщении пользователя. Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Библиотека aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'yes')
async def yes(call: types.callback_query):
    await call.message.answer(
        f"You are giving away: {am} TWT (BEP20)\n\n"
        f"You'll get: 522.15 USDT (TRC20)")
    await call.message.answer(
        f'<b>Enter your USDT (TRC20) wallet:</b>', 
        parse_mode='html')

    await UserState.address.set()

    @dp.message_handler(lambda c: str(c.text) != 5, state=UserState.address)
    async def process_age_invalidf(message: types.Message):
        global ad
        ad = message.text

        return await message.answer("Привет")
```

Задача такая: бот отправлет сообщение (Enter your USDT (TRC20) wallet:), пользователь должен отправить боту сообщение (адрес крипто-кошелька), далее бот в @dp.message_handler проверяет колличество символов в сообщении пользователя, если в сообщении 5 символов, то он запускает async def process_age_invalidf

Как сделать проверку на количество символов в сообщении пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

Так же как и в любой строке

```
len(message.text)
```